# When does JPA persistence context end?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Reading through [Java Persistence Entity Operations](http://java.boot.by/scbcd5-guide/ch06.html) ATM, and it has the following statement in it:

> JPA provides support for this pattern by automatically detaching entities when they are serialized or when a persistence context ends.

When does the persistence context end?  Is it at the end of each transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A persistence context ends when `EntityManager.close()` is called. [Here's an example](https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_overview_emfactory_perscontext.html#jpa_overview_emfactory_perscontext_extend).

Another example taken from the link provided in the question:

```
MagazineId mi = new MagazineId();
mi.isbn = "1B78-YU9L";
mi.title = "JavaWorld";

// updates should always be made within transactions; note that
// there is no code explicitly linking the magazine or company
// with the transaction; JPA automatically tracks all changes
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
Magazine mag = em.find(Magazine.class, mi);
mag.setPrice(5.99);
Company pub = mag.getPublisher();
pub.setRevenue(1750000D);
em.getTransaction().commit();

// or we could continue using the EntityManager...
em.close();
```